# Why would I use if and let together, instead of just checking if the original variable is nil? (Swift)

Tags: swift

In [“The Swift Programming Language.”](https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l) book, Apple mentions using `if` and `let` together when accessing an optional variable.

The book gives the following code for example:

```
var optionalString: String? = "Hello"
optionalString == nil

var optionalName: String? = "John Appleseed"
var greeting = "Hello!"
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

What is the advantage of using `if let name = optionalName`, rather than `if optionalName != nil` (and always referring to it as, `optionalName`)? Is there any difference, or is it simply convention?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it also unwraps the optional value, so this code:

```
if let name = optionalName {
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
if optionalName != nil {
    let name:String = optionalName!
    greeting = "Hello, \(name)"
}
```

This language sugar is known as [Optional Binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_432) in Swift.

### Optional Types

In Swift `T` and `T?` are not the same types, but the underlying value of an optional `T?` type can easily be realized by using the `!` postfix operator, e.g:

```
let name:String = optionalName!
```

Which now can be used where a `String` is expected, e.g:

```
func greet(name:String) -> String {
    return "Hello, \(name)"
}

greet(name)
```

Although as its safe to do so, Swift does let you implicitly cast to an optional type:

```
let name = "World"
let optionalName: String? = name

func greet(optionalName:String?) -> String? {
    if optionalName != nil {
        return "Hello, \(optionalName)"
    }
    return nil
}

//Can call with either String or String?
greet(optionalName)
greet(name)
```

Comment: Do optionals have to be unwrapped into another variable before they can be used?

Comment: It does if you want to use it where it's unwrapped value is expected, i.e. `T` and `T?` are not the same types.

Comment: So `greeting = "Hello, \(optionalName)"` would not work in the second example?

Comment: @mythz you should add that comment to your answer. It's very important the notion of `T` versus `T?`

Comment: Are you sure it unwraps the optional? I can't test right now, but when I last tried Im pretty sure name was still an optional

Comment: @connor: It unwraps it. It's called [optional binding](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_432).

Comment: `"Hello, \(optionalName)"` would work as well because (if I got that correctly) string interpolation automatically unwraps the value. But `"hello " + optionalName` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't actually needed in that case. You could just use optionalName in the if. But if optionalName was a calculated property it would have to be calculated in the conditional then again in the body. Assigning it to name just makes sure it is only calculated once.