# How can I use the fromRaw() function of enum

Tags: swift

I create a enum like the following and I try to use the fromRaw() function.

```
enum Test : Int {
    case a = 1
    case b, c
    func description() -> String{
        switch self {
        case .a:
            return "a"
        default:
            return String(self.toRaw())
        }
    }
}
```

It works in the situation I use like this. The bvalue.description() gives me the result "2".

```
if let bvalue = Test.fromRaw(2) {
    bvalue.description()
}
```

But when I try to use it without If statement, like the following. It gives me a wrong notification on the second line said "Invalid use of '()' to call a value of a non-function type String."

```
let bvalue = Test.fromRaw(2)
bvalue.description()
```

I was confused. What is the difference within If or without If statement? Why the second way cannot work? What type is this fromRaw() function returned?

Comment: Can you please format your code correctly to make it more readable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would I use if and let together, instead of just checking if the original variable is nil? (Swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049377/why-would-i-use-if-and-let-together-instead-of-just-checking-if-the-original-va)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.fromRaw()` method returns an optional value of your enumeration. So instead of `bvalue` having type `Test`, it has type `Test?`. In order to access its value you need to either unwrap it with an `if let...` like your example or force the unwrapping with the `!` operator:

```
bvalue!.description()
```

Note that if the `.fromRaw()` call failed, you'll get a runtime error. Try this to see it:

```
let bvalue = Test.fromRaw(5)   // 5 is out of bounds, bvalue == nil
bvalue!.description()          // runtime error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
```

Comment: Note that `fromRaw()` is no longer part of the Swift language. Instead, now one uses a failable initializer, like this: `if let bvalue = Test(rawValue: 2) { ... }`

Comment: `fromRaw()` has been depreciated; update the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Note that *fromRaw()* no longer exists.  The new usage would be:

```
Test(rawValue: 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in the second snippet you posted `bvalue` is optional. This means that a possible value of the `bvalue` variable is `nil`. Using the if statement "unwraps the optional" to either nil or the raw value. You can read more about this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_185).

Answer (score 0):

The `fromRaw()` function returns an Optional enum, in your case `Test?`, which might contain a `Test` `enum`, or be `nil`

Prior to using it, you must unwrap it, which is exactly what you are doing with the `if-let` pattern

If you try to access the description directly, it results in the compiler error.

You can also force unwrap an optional value with the `!` operator, as in `bvalue!.description`. But you should only use it in situations where it's clear that the Optional contains an actual value and is not `nil`. Using it in a situation where the value is `nil` results in a runtime error.